# How to add to associate array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array

```
$data = array('key1'=>'val1',
              'key2'=>'val2',
              'key3'=>'val3'
             );
```

I would like to add to the array.

```
$moreval = array('key4'=>'val4');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) for this.

```
$data=array_merge($data, array('key4'=>'val4'));
```

If this wasn't associative, you could use [array_push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php).

Answer (score 0):

you could just use:

> $data['key4'] = 'val4';